firebaseの各種サービスやSDKのバージョンのEOL等の通知設定について
firebaseの各種サービス(直近の例であればDynamicLinkの廃止やFCMのHTTP1移行など)やSDKのバージョン等のEOLを見流さないため、メールでの通知設定を導入しようと考えております。該当のメール通知設定導入の際に不明点があるため質問致します。
質問
①EOLのメールを受け取る設定は以下認識でお間違い無いでしょうか。
1.farebaseにログイン
2.farebaseコンソール画面右上のfarebaseアラート→アラート設定をクリック
3.ニュースとイベントの項目にチェックをいれる
②EOLメールを受領できるユーザーに関して、プロジェクト設定→ユーザーと権限にて権限が編集者、オーナーとなっているユーザーの認識でお間違い無いでしょうか。
③slackのメールアドレス等任意のメールアドレスを指定してEOL通知を送信することは可能でしょうか。
以上、ご確認をお願いいたします。

当サイトは主にプログラミングに関する質問をやり取りする場ですが、今回の質問は Firebase のサービス内容に関するものに見えるので、サポートへの問い合わせ を優先すべきように見えます。
